# Issue about extending Optional with Generic Type in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, option-type

I was trying to make an extension for safe unwrapping, and I was working in 2 version of it, one long code form, second short code! But unexpectedly they do not work! So far as I can see to my code, I just made all things correct! What I am missing to fix both version?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let test: String? = "Hello, World!"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(test.safeUnwrapV1(defaultValue: "Empty!"))
        Text(test.safeUnwrapV2(defaultValue: "Empty!"))
    }
    
}


extension Optional {    
    func safeUnwrapV1<T>(defaultValue: T) -> T {
        let wrappedValue: T? = (self as? T?) ?? nil
        if let unwrappedValue: T = wrappedValue { return unwrappedValue }
        else { return defaultValue }
    }
    
    func safeUnwrapV2<T>(defaultValue: T) -> T {
        return (self as? T) ?? defaultValue
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You aren't actually passing in different types, so what's the point of the casting? Also, there is already an operator for this, you could simply do `Text(test ?? "Empty!")`, no need for an overcomplicated custom function for that.

Comment: Yes, but I am interested in dot form, like: `test.safeUnwrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
extension Optional {
    func safeUnwrap(_ defaultValue: Wrapped) -> Wrapped {
        switch self {
            case let value?: return value
            case nil: return defaultValue
        }
    }
}
```

Or even

```swift
extension Optional {
  func safeUnwrap(_ defaultValue: Wrapped) -> Wrapped {
    self ?? defaultValue
  }
}
```

But as was pointed out, this is more wordy and less idiomatic than just using the `??` operator.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to define your own generic type parameter. `Optional` is already generic and its generic type parameter is called `Wrapped`. So you simply need to declare the type of the default value to be `Wrapped`.

```
extension Optional {
    func defaultValue(_ value: Wrapped) -> Wrapped {
        self ?? value
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let test: String? = "Hello, World!"

    var body: some View {
        Text(test.defaultValue("Empty!"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your extension like this.

```
extension Optional {
    
    func safeUnwrapV1<T>(defaultValue: T) -> Wrapped {
        
        guard let value = self else {
            return defaultValue as! Wrapped
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** As @Rudedog suggest no need to define generic here

```
extension Optional {
    func safeUnwrapV1(defaultValue: Wrapped) -> Wrapped {
        
        guard let value = self else {
            return defaultValue
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what is `Wrapped` here? is a Generic?

Comment: Wrapped from the Optional<Wrapped>.

Comment: Why use a template method here when you already know the type of Wrapped. You're just setting yourself up for a runtime crash.

Comment: @Rudedog: what would be better then?

Comment: @swiftPunk it would be better to not use a template method and not do a forced coercion.

Answer (score 0):

I would constrain `Optional` generic `Wrapped` type to `LosslessStringConvertible`:

---

```
extension LosslessStringConvertible {
    var string: String { .init(self) }
}
```

---

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: LosslessStringConvertible {
    var string: String { self?.string ?? "" }
    func string(default value: Wrapped) -> String {
        self?.string ?? value.string
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
var double1 = Double("2.7")
var double2 = Double("a")

print(double1.string(default: 0))
print(double2.string(default: 0))
```

This would print:

> 2.7
> 0

Comment: I do not want just work on String! Your work and your code focused on returning kind of String! that was not what I wanted! see my question please, I wanted change optional to non optional in snap! with an extension. like this: `test.safeUnwrap(...)` so it is not just String! It can my any Type or Custom Type as well.

Comment: @swiftPunk this is not constrained to String. As you can see I am using it on a Double. But anyway this is just to allow any type that can be converted to string to be easily unwrapped. Regarding the other types that can not be converted to a string you can use the already accepted posted solution which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks for advice.

Comment: I would just change the method name to something like `func safelyUnwrapped(with defaultValue: Wrapped) -> Wrapped {`

Comment: and if you want to use a switch `switch self {` `case let .some(value): return value` `case .none: return defaultValue` `}`