# Cast Int? to a String in a Text Component

Tags: swift, swiftui, casting

Is there a simple way of casting an optional Int to a String in SwiftUI and displaying it?

Ideally without having to check for `nil` while also having a default `Int` of `0`?

```swift
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        workout.duration != nil ? Text(String(workout.duration ?? 0)) : nil
    }
}
```

Comment: only Text(String("\\(workout.duration ?? 0)")) if you have a default 0, if I understand your question ... :)  ... thanks George for style correction

Comment: I highly recommend you rework `workout` so that `duration` is not optional (or replace `duration` with `durationDescription` that does all of this). A tiny amount of work in your view model will make your views dramatically simpler. Does it really make sense for a workout to have no duration (not even 0; literally nothing)? If not, why does workout allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some examples, first unwrapping Int with default option

```
 Text("\(workDuration ?? 0)")
```

Second case not to show a default text, and not to draw object Text (paddings, modifiers associates)

```
 if let workDuration != nil { Text("\(workDuration ?? 0)") }
```

Third more elegant as suggested by George, same as second option

```
 if let workDuration = workDuration { Text("\(workDuration)") }
```

Four, following Rob Napier's comment, unwrapping your model

```
  struct Workout {
    var duration: Int?
    var durationDescription : String {
         "\(duration ?? 0)"
    }
  }
  
  struct ContentView: View {
    let workout = Workout(duration: 33) //sample

    var body: some View {
       Text("\(workout.durationDescription)")
    }
 }
```

Comment: `workDuration` will never be nil inside the `if` in this case, so would probably be good for an `if let workDuration = workDuration { ... }`

Comment: In terms of naming is there a convention for something like `durationDescription`?

Comment: In my opinion we use description cause we follow an instance property description of protocol CustomStringConvertible, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/customstringconvertible/1539130-description

Answer (score 0):

Here an other way would be like this using extension:

```
extension Optional {
  func safeUnwrap(_ defaultValue: Wrapped) -> Wrapped {
    self ?? defaultValue
  }
}
```

---

```
// use case:

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text(String(describing: workout.duration.safeUnwrap(0)))  // <<: Here!
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use that extension that I provided with LosslessStringConvertible you don't need String(describing:) initializer

Comment: I have updated my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69020290/2303865) so you can pass any generic type as the default instead of a string in case of nil.

Comment: You can also make it even more flexible making the method generic `func string<T: LosslessStringConvertible>(default value: T) -> String {`

Comment: @LeoDabus: But this my code is better for me at least, because I have an option for getting safe value before I am going decide to use it as String form or not! At least I get Int at first! then I convert to String in place like this that we need String. If I wanted get Int, I must convert your result to Int and again another safe unwrapping would be needed!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
    if let str = value {
     print(str.description) // .description will convert it into text format
    }
```